# Convert a list of dictionaries into a set of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

How can i make a set of dictionaries from one list of dictionaries?

Example:

```
import copy

v1 = {'k01': 'v01', 'k02': {'k03': 'v03', 'k04': {'k05': 'v05'}}}
v2 = {'k11': 'v11', 'k12': {'k13': 'v13', 'k14': {'k15': 'v15'}}}

data = []
N = 5
for i in range(N):
    data.append(copy.deepcopy(v1))
    data.append(copy.deepcopy(v2))

print data
```

How would you create a set of dictionaries from the list `data`?

NS: One dictionary is equal to another when they are structurally the same. That means, they got **exactly** the same keys and same values (recursively)

Comment: What is your required tuple output?

Comment: `data = set(data)`?

Comment: @ForceBru `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Could you expand upon your question a bit? This seems like an exotic solution to a problem that may be better solved otherwise.

Comment: @BPL  Shouldn't the title of question be `Convert a dictionary of dictionaries into a set of dictionaries` instead of "Convert a list of dictionaries into a set of dictionaries"? i.e `list` -> `dict`. I am still confused regarding the question

Comment: The [forzendict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/frozendict) package provides *frozendicts* that are immutable and hashable, so you can create a set of those.

Comment: @TimFuchs: But within set, if two different `frozendict` objects are there even with the same structure. It will be treated at different entitity. I do not think this is what user wants

Comment: @TimFuchs Mmm, not sure about the [__hash__](https://github.com/slezica/python-frozendict/blob/master/frozendict/__init__.py#L36) function provided by frozendict, let me test it and I'll find a counterexample

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Judging by the hash function, having the same keys and values produces the same hash, so that fulfulls the OP requirements.

Comment: @BPL, it you don't like their hash, you could use the one from [PEP 416](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0416/#id9) (`hash(frozenset(dict.items()))`)

Comment: @TimFuchs Edited my answer, I'm getting an error using frozendict package

Comment: You need frozendicts of frozendicts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - List of unique dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511/python-list-of-unique-dictionaries)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A cheap workaround would be to serialize your dicts, for example:

```
import json

dset = set()

d1 = {'a':1, 'b':{'c':2}}
d2 = {'b':{'c':2}, 'a':1} # the same according to your definition
d3 = {'x': 42}

dset.add(json.dumps(d1, sort_keys=True))
dset.add(json.dumps(d2, sort_keys=True))
dset.add(json.dumps(d3, sort_keys=True))

for p in dset:
    print json.loads(p)
```

In the long run it would make sense to wrap the whole thing in a class like `SetOfDicts`.

Comment: Nice one! I haven't been able yet to find any counterexample, it seems it works even when keys are shuffled at deep levels of the dictionaries

Comment: @BPL: of course this only works as long as your dicts (and all sub-elements) are serializable.

Comment: Fair enough, I can live with that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are mutable and therefore not hashable in python.

You could either create a dict-subclass with a `__hash__` method. Make sure that the hash of a dictionary does not change while it is in the set (that probably means that you cannot allow modifying the members).
See http://code.activestate.com/recipes/414283-frozen-dictionaries/ for an example implementation of frozendicts.

If you can define a sort order on your (frozen) dictionaries, you could alternatively use a data structure based on a binary tree instead of a set. This boils down to the bisect solution provided in the link below.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/18824158/5069869 for an explanation why sets without hash do not make sense.

Comment: Ok, you've pointed out something is already well-known, no solution to the question though

Comment: What was your question? Why do you want a set? Do you only want to remove duplicates? Do you want to use set operations?

Comment: @BPL If you already know that `dict` are not `hashable`, then your question has no point. How can you then make set of `dicts`? Either you can make set of `keys` in `dict`, `values` in dict or `both`, BUT not dict itself

Answer (score 0):

not exactly what you're looking for as this accounts for lists too but:

```
def hashable_structure(structure):
    if isinstance(structure, dict):
        return {k: hashable_structure(v) for k, v in structure.items()}
    elif isinstance(structure, list):
        return {hashable_structure(elem) for elem in structure)}
    else:
        return structure
```

Answer (score -1):

Riffing off of georg's answer - who has the meat of it;
But, more succinctly:

```
set(json.dumps(i, sort_keys=True) for i in data)
```

where data is your list of dicts